# show that the maximum degree of the graph is 6

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let p1, p2, . . . , pn be n points in the plane such that the distance between any two points is
at least one. Let G = (V, E) be the graph such that V = {p1, p2, . . . , pn} and E = {pipj
|
distance between pi and pj
is exactly one}. Show that ∆(G) = 6.

Comment: Is $\Delta(G)$ the maximum degree of $G$?

Comment: Yes, it is the maximum degree of G

Comment: Are you sure the problem is asking you to prove $\Delta(G)=6$ and not $\Delta(G)\le6$? I can think of an example with $\Delta(G)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the statement you are likely expected to prove is that $\Delta(G)\color{red}{\leq}6$, not $\Delta(G)=6$.

Suppose for purposes of contradiction that $\Delta(G)>6$.  Then there is some vertex $v$ where $\deg(v)\geq 7$.  Without loss of generality, let $\deg(v)$ specifically be $\deg(v)=7$.

Then, there will be exactly seven vertices at distance exactly one away from $v$ and will lie somewhere along the circle:

[image]

Breaking the region around the circle into angular segments as pictured above, for example with angles ranging from $[k\frac{\pi}{3},(k+1)\frac{\pi}{3})$ for each segment $k=0,\dots,5$, by pigeon-hole principle there must be two vertices within the same segment.

Using a geometrical argument, you may then show that two vertices within the same segment will be at distance strictly less than one apart from one another, contradicting the fact that all vertices must be at distance *at least* one.